# Efficient CASE Statements, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Here is my query:

```
select col1, col2, (<a fairly complex query> as col3) from <a table>
```

`<a fairly complex query>` may return `NULL`, in which case I want to set `col3` to `col2`. I know I could do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
select col1, col2, 
CASE WHEN (<a fairly complex query>) is NULL col2
ELSE (<a fairly complex query>) END AS col3 
from <a table>
```

However, that approach executes `<a fairly complex query>` twice. What are some options if I only want to execute `<a fairly complex query>` once?

Comment: you can `left join` the complex query to the the table being used.

Comment: Use [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use subquery and `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, COALESCE(col3, col2) AS col3
FROM (select col1, col2, (<a fairly complex query>) as col3 
      from <a table>) AS sub;
```

Without subquery:

```
SELECT col1, col2, COALESCE(<a fairly complex query>, col2) AS col3
FROM <a table>;
```

Comment: That query leaves me with two `col3`s. The only way around that would be to explicitly list the columns I want rather than using `*`?

Comment: @Adam Yes, `*` is antipattern. Period. You should explicitly name columns.

Comment: OK. The query works without `AS sub`. What's the reason to include that part?

Comment: It is just alias for subquery, so you could write `SELECT sub.col1, sub.col2,` and so on. Useful for readability perspective or if you want to join subquery to another table

Comment: @Adam It shouldn't work without `AS sub`, since "*Every derived table must have its own alias*". However I would use the subquery in the SELECT clause and avoid an unnecessary temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, but eliminates the need for a subquery:

```
select col1, col2, COALESCE(<a fairly complex query>, col2) AS col3 from <a table>
```